# Web Api c# Get Query Sring from url - Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I got a url where it's method is post but I want to  pass some paramets by get method, I am using c# MVC asp.net

as the follow link
http://site/api/user/seach/?value=here&value2=here2

I am trying to  get  this using

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
 {
    var queryString = this.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
 }
```

And I already  tried to  use

```
string p =  Request.QueryString["value"];
```

But it seems to  work only in controller base exteds

Is there some way to get this value get  in a post method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'd like to use the `POST` verb but send data through querystring, in that case you can:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri]string value)
{
    // do whatever you need to do here
}
```